# Using Query Scope but with different query model - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

User can Register for Multiple Tournaments and
Each Tournament has one Score record for each user.

[image: Relationship Diagram]

I have kept user_id in Score table to keep the records unique.

I have this Query :

```
$tournaments = DB::table('tournaments')
        ->join('scores','tournaments.id','=','scores.tournament_id')
        ->select('tournaments.*','scores.score','scores.tees')
        ->where('t_date','<',Carbon::today())
        ->where('scores.user_id',$request->user()->id)
        ->get();
```

I wanted to avoid joins and also use Query Scope for re-use of where clause `'(t_date < Carbon::today())'`

So, this is the query I have come up with:

```
//This is in Tournament Model
public function scopeUpcoming($query)
{
        return $query->where('t_date','>',Carbon::today());
}

$query = Score::with('tournaments')
         ->upcoming()
         ->where('user_id',$request->user()->id)
         ->get();
```

But scopeUpcoming() uses $query and there is no 't_date' in Score table, so I need to somehow access tournaments table and query on it. vice-versa I can't go with Tournament::with('scores') as there is no 'user_id' in Tournament's table so I cant get for a specific user.

Comment: And what is the reason for avoiding joins?

Comment: I have lots of Joins in my controllers and I find joins and raw queries are kind of hacks and I am making least use of Eloquent models. I want to learn MVC framework the way its designed to use. I am trying to avoid single/multiple joins and want to use eloquent relationships more effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you can't go with

> `Tournament::with('scores')` there is no `user_id` in Tournament's table so I cant get for a specific user.

Actually, you can still use `with` method and you can filter the items using a closure:

```php
Tournament::with(['scores' => function($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
});
```

---

Also you said:

> I need to somehow access tournaments table and query on it

You can use the same bit of code to modify your current query chain

```php
$query = Score::with(['tournaments' => function($query) {
             $query->with('t_date, /**/); // Do your stuff here.
         ])
         ->upcoming()
         ->where('user_id',$request->user()->id)
         ->get();
```

Hope this light up your case.

Comment: I am really confused now. What goes as query Scope and what goes in controller? Where do I add upcomingScope()? Can you please explain or show what bit goes where? I tried so many alternatives

Comment: This is what I got : [{"id":1,"tournament_id":2,"user_id":2,"score":45,"tees":"championship","tournaments":null}] tournaments result seems to be empty whereas there is tournament_id : 2, it says null? whereas its not. $query = Score::with(['tournaments' => function($query) use ($user_id) {
             $query->where('t_date','<',Carbon::today());
            }
         ])
         ->where('user_id',$request->user()->id)
         ->get();

Comment: Wait, wait, the “scope function” is something you put on your models. In the controller you can put all your logic (in your case the query).